# aws sdk nodejs: check if there is any users online

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

Is there a way to find out which user is still online? I read somewhere that I cannot do that directly, but use the sessions to check either anyone is online. If it possible to get user sessions without having to know user credentials?

Or is that is an alternative way that i can do to get find out which users are still online?

Comment: How about something google analytics? It has realtime stats

Comment: No I don’t have access to that.

Comment: What user sessions ? What is the service you want go get user data from ?

Comment: Cognito user session, need to know if any users within an environment active. I hope I make sense with this.